Load pull testing transceiver LNA input, impedance tuner DIY alternative
Transceiver vendors not always provide best components for input impedance matching in all variety of frequencies range that transceiver itself support, often provide impedance matching network components only for single range of frequencies and some instruction how to get best matching for custom frequencies. And this method involve pretty complex & expensive devices, and if some devices became more affordable with time(VNA) some rare devices so far hard to find for reasonable price.
Any homemade alternative could be done for variable impedance tuner in range from 400 MHz-1 GHz ? I am generally get idea how variable impedance tuners works, but some details not clear and this not fully allowed me to think about alternatives that could be fit here, if get few used coaxial adjustable stub(tuning line) connect it with each other, could this cover varies of impedances ?
